# How to customize the taskboard in TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs-2012

I've installed TFS 2012 RC, and managed to customize my work item types to add custom fields, and also an additional state.

I would like to be able to see this additional state between the In progress column, and the Done columnd and didn't found a way to do this.

Any ideas about how to achieve the customization of the board (I'm using the SCRUM template).

Regards,