# In TFS2012, how do you change what's displayed in the task board?

Tags: tfs

When I navigate to the Task Board in TFS2012 Web Access, there is a message stating the following:

> The task board cannot be displayed because it is empty.  You have
>   configured the task board to show work scheduled for the following
>   iteration: BP5578-CouponMaint\Sprint 001.

I have no idea how this was configured (or whether it's really just a default). How do I configure which iteration shows on the Task Board?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the taskboard in TFS 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917457/how-to-customize-the-taskboard-in-tfs-2012)

Comment: It's not. That question is about customizing the content shown. This is about figuring out what batch of work is shown at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The taskboard will show the current iteration, which is based on the iteration dates you configured.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sprint shown will be current one. This is based on going into the Settings "cog" and then Iterations, and finding the ones that are ticked and has today's date in it's date range, in your case it will be: `BP5578-CouponMaint\Sprint 001`. Along side it, there should be other sprints and the dates that these sprints cover.